# What is the sum of series $1+\frac1{3\cdot4^1}+\frac1{5\cdot4^2}+\frac1{7\cdot4^3}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve this series question which is

$$1+\frac1{3\cdot4^1}+\frac1{5\cdot4^2}+\frac1{7\cdot4^3}+\cdots$$

Till now I've only been able to write the general form of this series which is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)4^{n-1}}$$

but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Consider the series
$$\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)$$
for $x=\dfrac12$.

Comment: I still don't get it sorry.

Comment: @kriti_sharma Write down the series for $\ln(1+x)$, and $\ln(1-x)$. Observe what the difference looks like when $x=1/2$. Although I haven't done it, I'm thinking it will look a lot like the series you're trying to sum, and the sum of that series is $\ln(3/2) - \ln(1/2).$ See?

Comment: @kriti_sharma If you can't come up with series expansion for log (having *alternating* coefficients) from your series (having *positive* coefficient), you may view my answer to know *how* log appears in the solution.

Comment: @GNUSupporter: Okay thanks!

Comment: @John: So it's taylor expansion?

Comment: @kriti_sharma Yes.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(2k-1)4^{k-1}} \\
=& \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2k+1)4^{k}} \\
=& \sum_{k=0}^\infty  4^{-k} \int_0^1 x^{2k} dx \\
=& \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^k dx \tag{Fubini-Tonelli Theorem} \\
=& \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x^2/4} dx \\
=& 2 \int_0^{1/2} \frac{1}{1-t^2} dt \tag{$t = x/2$} \\
=& \int_0^{1/2} \left( \frac{1}{1-t} + \frac{1}{1+t} \right) dt \tag{$t = x/2$} \\
=& \left[ -\ln|1-t| + \ln|1+t| \right]_0^{1/2} \\
=& -\ln(1/2) + \ln(3/2) \\
=& \ln 3
\end{align}

Comment: I have a question: In step 3 how did you introduce the x variable?

Comment: @kriti_sharma $$\int_0^1 x^{2k} dx = \frac{1}{2k+1}$$

Comment: thank you got it!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Reindexing your expression for the series for convenience gives
$$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{2 k + 1} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^k .$$

Now, the factors $\frac{1}{2 k + 1}$ suggest considering the power series
$$\operatorname{artanh} x \sim \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{2 k + 1} x^{2 k + 1} .$$

> Rewrite the given series to get $$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{2 k + 1} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^k = 2 \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{2 k + 1} \left(\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{2 k + 1} = 2 \operatorname{artanh} \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}} = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}\log \frac{1 + \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}}{1 - \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}} = \boxed{\log 3} .$$